# Citation Style (CSL) with angular quotation marks?

Tags: citation-style, reference-managers

I'm writing a chapter to go in a book produced in South America, and they want us to use angular quotation marks. Two example formats I have look like:

- Klaveren, Alberto van. «Doscientos años de la política exterior de Chile: de Hobbes a Grocio». Artaza, Mario y César Ross (eds.), La política exterior de Chile, 1990-2009. Del aislamiento a la integración global, USACH-RIL editores, 2012, pp. 51-69.
- Witker, Iván. «La anarquía latinoamericana desde una perspectiva neorrealista», en Estudios Avanzados 12, diciembre 2009, pp. 23-41.

I tried using the [CSL Search By Example](https://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/) page, but nothing with angle-quotes appeared in the search results.  Furthermore all the examples found put the year in the wrong place (they put it near the beginning and I need it near the end).

Can anyone suggest an appropriate CSL format and where to find it, or else how can I modify a "similar" CSL file to meet my requirements? (I still find the [Visual Editor](https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/) super-confusing.) Thanks.

(Writing in Google Docs, with citations managed by Zotero and its Google Docs connector.)

Answer (score -1):

Adding the angle-brackets was as simple as using the *Visual Editor* and clicking on titles for article examples and then adding the « to the Prefix and » to the Suffix fields down below.

Moving the year took a little more than just dragging and dropping it. Downloaded the modified CSL and applied it to Zotero in Doc, and results seem to be very close to what I need.